# Session work on cross domains on localhost

Tags: php, session, localhost, web-hosting

First i am creating my website on localhost using `XAMPP`.

My website ask the user to login and if the information is right then a session start called `$_SESSION['id_session']` and here is the code :

```
                    if($userExist == 1){
                        $_SESSION['id_session'] = $getId;
                        echo "t";
                    }
```

So after the logging in there is a session that start and contain the user id.

The problem here is that if I opened another offline website on my xampp that have the same session that is called `$_SESSION['id_session']` then this session share its value with the other website..

Is this thing occurs when my website goes online?!

Comment: `localhost` is a single domain...